# Multiple apps installation using a single dmg on Mac OS

Tags: macos, installation, dmg

In windows, I can pack multiple .exe files as part of asingle installer (.msi) using wix. Similarly, is it possible to pack multiple .app files as part of a single dmg file and let the user install it?
Say for Eg:
I have App X, App Y and App Z.  I should be able to install all the three applications by using  'Installer.dmg' . Please let me know if it is possible and  how.

Comment: It's a disk image, you can put whatever you want on it. What is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 2):

You can always add multiple .apps in a DMG. But this requires the user to click and drag the apps one by one to /Applications directory (if this is what you are looking for).

If you are looking for an installer like Windows installers, you can create a PKG file. PKG can be embedded in DMG. Click on the PKG file will launch an installer.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/34613/packages - This is one tool that allows you to create a PKG file. PKG even allows you to have pre-install and post-install scripts. http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/index.html is the user guide for Packages tool

Comment: Thanks Seema. Pkg is what I was looking for.