# How can I bundle a precompiled binary with electron

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, electron

I am trying to include a precompiled binary with an electron app.  I began with electron quick start app and modified my `renderer.js` file to include this code that is triggered when a file is dropped on the body:

```js
spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  ffmpeg = spawn('node_modules/.bin/ffmpeg', ['-i', clips[0], '-an', '-q:v', '1', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-y', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-vf', 'setsar=1,scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,crop=in_w:in_h-50:0:50', '/tmp/out21321.mp4']);

ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
```

I have placed my precompiled **ffmpeg** binary in `node_modules/.bin/`.  Everything works great in the dev panel, but when I use electron-packager to set up the app, it throws a `spawn error ENOENT` to the console when triggered.  I did find a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152533/bundling-precompiled-binary-into-electron-app?s=1%7C0.5909) on SO, but the question doesn't seem to be definitively answered.  The  [npm page on electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager) does show that they can be bundled, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do so.

Comment: This page tells you what you need to know: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-packaging/

So either: Use child_process.execFile, or don't use asar packaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone happens to need an answer to this question: I do have a solution to this, but I have no idea if this is considered best practice. I couldn't find any good documentation for including 3rd party precompiled binaries, so I just fiddled with it until it finally worked. Here's what I did (starting with the electron quick start, node.js v6):

From the app directory I ran the following commands to include the ffmpeg binary as a module:

```
mkdir node_modules/ffmpeg
cp /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg node_modules/ffmpeg/
ln -s ../ffmpeg/ffmpeg node_modules/.bin/ffmpeg
```

(replace /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg with your current binary path, download it from here) Placing the link allowed electron-packager to include the binary I saved to node_modules/ffmpeg/.

Then to get the bundled app path I installed the npm package app-root-dir by running the following command:

```
npm i -S app-root-dir
```

Since I could then get the app path, I just appended the subfolder for my binary and spawned from there. This is the code that I placed in renderer.js:.

```
var appRootDir = require('app-root-dir').get();
var ffmpegpath=appRootDir+'/node_modules/ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
console.log(ffmpegpath);

const
    spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn,
    ffmpeg = spawn( ffmpegpath, ['-i',clips_input[0]]);  //add whatever switches you need here

ffmpeg.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
     console.log( `stdout: ${data}` );
    });
   ffmpeg.stderr.on( 'data', data => {
console.log( `stderr: ${data}` );
    });
```

Answer (score 39):

The problem is that `electron-builder` or `electron-packager` will bundle your dependency into the `asar` file. It seems that if the dependency has a binary into `node_modules/.bin` it is smart enough to not package it.

This is the [documentation for asar packaging](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#Config-asar) for `electron-builder` on that topic. It says

> Node modules, that must be unpacked, will be detected automatically

I understand that it is related to existing binaries in `node_modules/.bin`.

If the module you are using is not automatically unpacked you can disable `asar` archiving completely or explicitly tell `electron-builder` to not pack certain files. You do so in your `package.json` file like this:

```
  "build": {
    "asarUnpack": [
      "**/app/node_modules/some-module/*"
    ],
```

### For your particular case

I ran into the same issue with `ffmpeg` and this is what I've done:

- Use [`ffmpeg-static`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-static). This package bundles statically compiled ffmpeg binaries for Windows, Mac and Linux. It also provides a way to get the full path of the binary for the OS you are running: `require('ffmpeg-static').path`
- This will work fine in development, but we still need to troubleshoot the distribution problem.
- Tell `electron-builder` to not pack the `ffmpeg-static` module:

  "build": {
      "asarUnpack": [
        "**/app/node_modules/ffmpeg-static/*"
      ],
- Now we need to slightly change the code to get the right path to `ffmpeg` with this code: `require('ffmpeg-static').path.replace('app.asar', 'app.asar.unpacked')` (if we are in development the `replace()` won't replace anything which is fine).

### If you are using webpack (or other javascript bundler)

I ran into the issue that `require('ffmpeg-static').path` was returning a relative path in the renderer process. But the issue seemed to be that webpack changes the way the module is required and that prevents `ffmpeg-static` to provide a full path. In the Dev Tools the `require('ffmpeg-static').path` was working fine when run manually, but when doing the same in the bundled code I was always getting a relative path. So this is what I did.

- In the main process add this before opening the `BrowserWindow`: `global.ffmpegpath = require('ffmpeg-static').path.replace('app.asar', 'app.asar.unpacked')`. The code that runs in the main process is not bundled by webpack so I always get a full path with this code.
- In the renderer process pick the value this way: `require('electron').remote.getGlobal('ffmpegpath')`

Comment: Maaan, I just spent ~24 hours on this one. Didn't know about the unpacked part. Cheers

Comment: This has been a great problem solver and time saver answer. Thank you.

Comment: Does this package only the binary needed for the OS, or does it include all binaries in every package (beefy).

Comment: @Trees4theForest if you're using electron-builder then you can specify which files go with which platform in your package.json, e.g. `{mac:{files:"bin/mac/*"},win:{files:"bin/win/*"}}`. See https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#files for more details.

Comment: I got an error putting the build setting in package.json. I added `vue.config.js` to my project directory with this:
`module.exports = {
    pluginOptions: {
      electronBuilder: {
        builderOptions: {
            "extraFiles":{
                "from":"node_modules/ffmpeg-static/bin",
                "to":"./resources/app.asar.unpacked/bin/"
                }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm a bit late but just wanted to mention `ffbinaries` npm package I created a while ago exactly for this purpose.

It'll allow you to download ffmpeg/ffplay/ffserver/ffprobe binaries to specified location either during application boot (so you don't need to bundle it with your application) or in a CI setup. It can autodetect platform, you can also specify it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the package, looks great!

Comment: This is better left as a comment, since it does not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

Taking cues from [tsuriga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45152204/1317099), here is my code:

Note: replace or add *OS* path accordingly.

- Create a directory *./resources/mac/bin*
- Place you binaries inside this folder
- Create file *./app/binaries.js* and paste the following code:

> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> import path from 'path';
> import { remote } from 'electron';
> import getPlatform from './get-platform';
>
> const IS_PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
> const root = process.cwd();
> const { isPackaged, getAppPath } = remote.app;
>
> const binariesPath =
>   IS_PROD && isPackaged
>     ? path.join(path.dirname(getAppPath()), '..', './Resources', './bin')
>     : path.join(root, './resources', getPlatform(), './bin');
>
> export const execPath = path.resolve(path.join(binariesPath, './exec-file-name'));
> ```

- Create file *./app/get-platform.js* and paste the following code:

> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> import { platform } from 'os';
>
> export default () => {
>   switch (platform()) {
>     case 'aix':
>     case 'freebsd':
>     case 'linux':
>     case 'openbsd':
>     case 'android':
>       return 'linux';
>     case 'darwin':
>     case 'sunos':
>       return 'mac';
>     case 'win32':
>       return 'win';
>   }
> };
> ```

- Add the following code inside the *./package.json* file:

> ```
> "build": {
> ....
>
>  "extraFiles": [
>       {
>         "from": "resources/mac/bin",
>         "to": "Resources/bin",
>         "filter": [
>           "**/*"
>         ]
>       }
>     ],
>
> ....
> },
> ```

- import binary file path as:

> ```
> import { execPath } from './binaries';
>
> #your program code:
> var command = spawn(execPath, arg, {});
> ```

**Why this is better?**

- Most of the answers require an additional package called *app-root-dir*
- The original answer doesn't handle the (env=production) *build* or the *pre-packed* versions properly. He/she has only taken care of development and post-packaged versions.