# Distributing Homebrew dependencies along with electron-packager

Tags: homebrew, dependency-management, software-distribution, electron-packager

I have an electron application that has the following dependencies:

1. `ffmpeg`
2. `libmagic`
3. `gdbm`

Currently, I use Homebrew and run `brew install ffmpeg` etc. upon startup of the app.

However, this is terrible for distribution. Is there a way to distribute these dependencies packaged alongside my application so that the end user doesn't have to have Homebrew or deal with installation errors? I'm distributing my app using `electron-packager` to create a Desktop Mac app.

I gave the specific dependencies just for context -- hopefully there is a solution that would work with any generic dependency?

Comment: This is a very broad question; please add more context regarding your app and how you distribute it.

Comment: @bfontaine added relevant details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361996/how-can-i-bundle-a-precompiled-binary-with-electron/43389268#43389268

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with dynamic linking

use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-static

**Example Usage**

Returns the path of a statically linked ffmpeg binary on the local filesystem.

```
var pathToFfmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');
console.log(pathToFfmpeg);
/Users/j/playground/node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg
```

check https://discuss.atom.io/t/information-about-bundled-ffmpeg/28456/6