# How to package a compiled binary with electron-builder on Mac?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a Mac electron app that calls a compiled binary that I wrote when a button is pressed. The way I have it set up is:

1. The binary (let's call it `test`) is placed in a `bin` folder, which sits in the root directory of the application.
2. From a Javascript file, I run

```
var appRootDir = require('app-root-path');
var path = appRootDir + '/bin/test';
const spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn;
var child = spawn( path, []);
```

whenever I want to start the binary This works great when I run the app locally via `npm start`. But, when I package it by running `electron-builder`, the binary fails to get called. I don't have this problem on Windows because `electron-builder` creates a folder containing the app and its files, but on Mac, everything seems to be condensed into one application. I've tried following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361996/how-can-i-bundle-a-precompiled-binary-with-electron) but it seems specific to ffmpeg/I couldn't get it to work.

Clearly I must be missing something--does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!